# aggregation module in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following records in my mongo database:

> db.new_student.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d7c986ddbf7aae989d7021"), "name" : "student_one", 
"start_time" : "2013-11-07T00:00:00:01Z", "end_time" : "2013-11-07T08:00:00:01Z", 
"usage" : 444 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d7c9b3ddbf7aae989d7022"), "name" : "student_one", 
"start_time" : "2013-11-08T00:00:00:01Z", "end_time" : "2013-11-08T08:00:00:01Z", 
"usage" : 1000 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d7c9c7ddbf7aae989d7023"), "name" : "student_one", 
"start_time" : "2013-12-08T00:00:00:01Z", "end_time" : "2013-12-08T08:00:00:01Z", 
"usage" : 100 }
```

I want generate a query using aggregation function of mongodb for students whose usage have dropped by more than a certain percentage from previous month.

In the above data for simplicity I have considered single student named as "student_one".
Can I do this by generating just one query ?

I am new to aggregation function provided by mongodb. Please let me know how can I do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe there is any easy way to do this in one call no

Comment: If not in one path please suggest me how can I do it in more then one call